# BeyondCompare: Compare with actual SVN-revision

Tags: svn, beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

I want to compare the actual revision in SVN with an older one.

I can define a profile for a specific revision:

[image: Subversion Profile in BC4]

But I found no way to define a subversion profile for the actual revision (when I use it later, then it should be the actual version, not the one, that was actual, when I created the profile).

How can I do it?

I tried an empty revision and a very high (actually not exosting) revision, but without success.

Comment: If you want to compare against HEAD just leave the Revision field blank.  If that's not working, what behavior are you seeing?

Comment: If I leave the revision empty, then I can't save the profile in BC4.